# Compiling a nested list with conditional statement

Tags: python

I want to create a nested list with one or more of the below lists of tuples, with the order of the list based on user's preference.

```
Fruits=[("Apples",2),("Oranges",3),("Pineapples",5)]
Clothes=[("Jeans",10),("Shirts",5),("Dresses",15)]
Pets=[("Dogs",3),("Cats",4),("Turtles",2)]
```

The order of the nested list will depend on the preference of the user.For instance, if the user prefer pets over clothes over fruits. The list will look like this:

```
[[("Jeans",10),("Shirts",5),("Dresses",15)],[("Jeans",10),("Shirts",5), 
("Dresses",15)],[("Apples",2),("Oranges",3),("Pineapples",5)]]
```

The user also have the option of picking only one or two items. For instance, if the user only cares about pet and then clothing (doesn't care about fruits), his/her list will look like this.

```
[[("Dogs",3),("Cats",4),("Turtles",2)],[("Jeans",10),("Shirts",5), 
("Dresses",15)]]
```

The user input is a list with the preferences in order. For example:

```
preference= ["Pets", "Fruits", "Clothing"] # preference list for users who care about pets over fruits over clothing.
            or 
preference= ["Fruits", "Clothing"] # preference list for users who care about fruits over clothing (no regard for pets)
```

This is how I've tried to tackle the problem. First I create an empty list with a corresponding number of nested list:

```
empty_list=[[] for x in range (len(preferences)]
```

This creates a place holder for the number of nested list I need. I then run a bunch of conditional statement to pop in one list at the time:

```
if preference[0]=="Fruits":
    empty_list[0]=Fruits
    if preference[1]=="Clothes":
        empty_list[1]=Clothes
        empty_list[2]=Pets
   elif preference[1]=="Pets":
        empty_list[1]=Pets
        empty_list[2]=Clothes

if preference[0]=="Pets":
    empty_list[0]=Pets
    if preference[1]=="Clothes":
        empty_list[1]=Clothes
        empty_list[2]=Fruits
    elif preference[1]=="Fruits":
        empty_list[1]=Fruits
        empty_list[2]=Clothes

if preference[0]=="Clothes":
    empty_list[0]=Clothes
    if preference[1]=="Pets":
        empty_list[1]=Pets
        empty_list[2]=Fruits
    elif preference[1]=="Fruits":
        empty_list[1]=Fruits
        empty_list[2]=Pets
```

My solution is inefficient and also causes problem with list assignment out of range if there are only two preference as opposed to three. Is there a more Pythonic way of writing this?

Any tip or guidance is most appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

you should store your data in a dictionary

and then access that dictionary by key

```
data = dict(
    Fruits=[("Apples",2),("Oranges",3),("Pineapples",5)]
    Clothes=[("Jeans",10),("Shirts",5),("Dresses",15)]
    Pets=[("Dogs",3),("Cats",4),("Turtles",2)]
)
```

once you have it in a dict you can easily access the values with variables

```
fruits = "Fruits"
my_fruits = data[fruits]
```

you can then use a simple list comprehension to capture all of your interests

```
interests = ["Fruits","Pets"]    
interesting_things = [data[interest] for interest in interests]

interests = ["Fruits","Clothes"]
interesting_things = [data[interest] for interest in interests]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this method.

```
def prefer(preference):
    preference_list = []

    choices = {
        "fruits": [
            ("Apples", 2),
            ("Oranges", 3),
            ("Pineapples", 5)
        ],
        "cloths": [
            ("Jeans", 10),
            ("Shirts", 5),
            ("Dresses", 15)
        ],
        "pets": [
            ("Dogs", 3),
            ("Cats", 4),
            ("Turtles", 2)
        ]
    }

    for choice in choices:
        if choice in preference:
            preference_list.insert(preference.index(choice), choices[choice])

        else:
            preference_list.append(choices[choice])


    print(preference_list)

prefer(("fruits", "cloths"))
```

Comment: This works great. Thank you! The only change I had to make was getting rid of the preference_list.append (choices[choice]) as the number of preference list can be fewer than 3.